# comparing times using datetime in php for a login script

Tags: php, datetime, authentication

Okay, so my problem is this: when a user has 3 failed login attempts, he/she is supposed to be locked out of his account for an hour based on IP address. The IP address is stored into the table 'login_attempts' along with the fields 'attempts' and 'time'. Here is my code to pull the time and then I add an hour to it because that's when it's supposed to be when the user can try to log in again:

```
$user_time = new DateTime('20:04:18');    // example time pulled from the db
$add = new DateInterval('PT1H');          // +1 hour
$user->add($add);                         // should now be 21:04:18
```

Ok, so now here is the code for the current time. Again, I'm going to make up a time. It's going to be less than an hour so the user should still be LOCKED out:

```
$now = new DateTime('20:43:22');
if ($now->format('g:i a') < $user_time->format('g:i a')) {
         $diff = $user_time->diff($now);
         echo 'You still have ' . $diff->format('%i minutes') . ' until you can try again.';
}
 else {
        // reset login attempts, process login
```

For some reason this doesn't work properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why is your condition no using diff instead of format?

Answer (score 0):

You better have a time field in your database table with int datatype and store the output of time() function for every login attempt. after the nth time unsuccessful attempts the user gets locked and initialize lockout. to check if the lockout time is over, simply compare the output of current time() function with the one stored after the third unsuccessful attempt.

```
$lockout = 3600;//if one hour
$query_result_for_last_attempt = "some query";
if((time()-$query_result_for_last_attempt) > $lockout){
header(site.php);
}else{
echo "you still need to wait";
}
```

of course there are beter fantacies you could do with the code!

Comment: ok, when the user fills in the form and clicks login, i get the users IP address and if it hasn't been put in the db already, it is added. then i check for the # of login attempts. if the login attempts are <= 2 and !valid, then display an error message and let the user try again. if the attempts == 3, display an error message and lockout. so if the user tries for a fourth time, i'm using the script above to check whether the current time > the time from the failed attempt stored in the database. i assume if it's greater than, it should be time to let the user login again, right?

Comment: That is right and you better see if the login has been successful, you need to update the login_attempts table, reset the attempt counter to 0.

Comment: ok...so let me get this straight: $lockout is 1 hour in seconds. the $query_result is going to be the time returned from the query to see when the last failed login attempt was. dont i want to add 1 hour to the query and THEN check to see if it is greater than $lockout?

Comment: You only need to compare the returned value of the query which is the last unsuccessful attempt for that specific IP address with the current attempt time().

Comment: the output of the time() is an integer! so try an integer for $query_result

Answer (score 0):

I think your comparing of the dates is the problem. Try using getTimestamp() instead of format():

```
$now = new DateTime('20:43:22');
if ($now->getTimestamp() < $user_time->getTimestamp()) {
         $diff = $user_time->diff($now);
         echo 'You still have ' . $diff->format('%i minutes') . ' until you can try again.';
}
 else {
        // reset login attempts, process login
```